# Marshmallow - Sort field values by declared order

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I've read the docs and searched this site but cannot seem to find a solution to sorting field values by the order in which they are declared. The docs state that adding `ordered = True` to the `class Meta` will solve this problem -

```
class MySchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        ordered = True
```

However, I am not using `class Meta` in my schema. My schema simply looks like -

```
class MySchema(Schema):    
    id = fields.Integer()
    name = fields.Str() 
    category = fields.Str()
```

So in this situation, how and where would I set `ordered = True`? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I solved the issue by changing my schema class to -

```
class MySchema(Schema):  
    class Meta:
        ordered = True  

    id = fields.Integer()
    name = fields.Str() 
    category = fields.Str()
```

and then also adding `JSON_SORT_KEYS=False` to my app's config.py file.